# Add a column of group averages in R

Tags: r

In this (made up) data frame df, I want to show the average age grouped by ID.

Output right now:

```
   ID age
    1  20
    1  25
   20  40
   20  35
   20  30
  356  27
 4001  22
 4001  49
 4001  46
 4001  75
55555  50
55555  54
```

Desired output:

```
   ID age  meanage
    1  20   22.5
    1  25   22.5
   20  40   35.0
   20  35   35.0
   20  30   35.0
  356  27   27.0
 4001  22   48.0
 4001  49   48.0
 4001  46   48.0
 4001  75   48.0
55555  50   52.0
55555  54   52.0
```

One solution that works is

```
for (i in min(df$ID):max(df$ID))
{
  df$meanage[df$ID == i] <- mean(df$age[df$ID == i])
}
```

However, this is really slow, especially for a very large data set. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` method to find the average "age" by "ID"

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,meanage:=mean(age)  , by = ID][]
```

Or a `base R` approach

```
df$meanage <- with(df, ave(age, ID))
```

Or using `dplyr` (contributed by @David Arenburg)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(meanage = mean(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use plyr

```
library(plyr)
x <- ddply(df,.(ID),summarise,ave=mean(age))
#same as (I think):
x <- ddply(df,~ID,summarise,meanage=mean(age))
```

If you want the average duplicated (as in your example) you can merge the new result onto it (there may be a way to avoid that step).